# Определить, с каких ip идет обращение к скриптам и файлам

Tags: php, javascript, apache

Допустим - есть определенный сайт на шаред хостинге. На сайте присутствуют файлы типа "site.ru/script.js" и "site.ru/img.jpg".

И есть определенные сайты, которые подключают эти файлы с помощью хотлинка.

Можно как-то определить ip сайтов и вообще любых юзеров запрашивающих эти файлы и сохранить их в какой-то отчет?

Comment: да, можно, но нужно отдавать файлы через php скрипт. header - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: подключите гугл аналитику

Comment: @madfan41k 21 и как она поможет определять ip?

Comment: вы ставите екшены на эти файлы и можете мониторить кто сколько раз и от куда смотрел ваши файлы

Comment: @Руслан `heaer` то тут при чем? файл на загрузку то отдавать  не надо, а просто вывести.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из наиболее простых решений будет вывод указанных файлов с помощью php-скрипта. Для этого можно настроить mod_rewrite, чтобы он перенаправлял запросы к указанным файлом на ваш скрипт:

```
RewriteRule    ^(script\.js)|(img\.jpg)$    log.php?file=$1    [L]
```

После чего запрос указанных файлов будет перенаправлен в файл `log.php`, а в качестве _GET параметра `file` будет указано имя файла.
В самом скрипте теперь вы можете выполнить необходимые процедуры логгирования и отдать контент файла.

```
<?php

    $file = $_GET['file'];
    // записать лог
    // ....

    // отдать файл   
    readfile($file);
```

для js файла впрочем можно сделать и еще проще,

```
<?php
    // логгируем доступ
?>
//текст вашего js-файла
alert("hello world!");
```

но,  пожалуй,первый вариант предпочтительней.

Вопрос будет в том, что и как вы будете логгировать и откуда получать сведения. Сайты, с которых приходит запрос к файлу, можно получить через `referer`, IP-адреса пользовтелей - через `remote_addr`.

Чтобы не записывать в лог свой собственный сайт, можете в `.htaccess` сделать соответствующую проверку а-ля `RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!www.example.com" [NC]`. Впрочем тут же можно просто напросто запретить доступ к файлам, если запрошены не с вашего сайта. Однако, надо понимать, что при прямом запросе к файлу этих заголовков не будет.